# Dynamically inserting an image on a home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, image-display

I'm creating a SharePoint template that I will apply to several hundred sites. I need a way to display an image on the homepage of a SharePoint Online site, where the image automatically updates whenever a new file is uploaded to a specific library path ("/General/Photos/DefaultPhoto.jpg"). Essentially, when a user replaces 'DefaultPhoto.jpg' with a new image (keeping the same file name), the change should be reflected on the homepage without any additional manual steps.

Current Approach:
Initially, I considered using the standard Image web part, but it doesn't dynamically update the image when the file at the specified path changes. The carousel does allow for dynamic content, but isn't resizeable or editable in any way and doesn't display portrat images very well.  My next thought is to develop a custom SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web part, but I'm still in the early stages of exploring this.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone has tackled a similar requirement or has suggestions on the best way to approach this. Specifically, I'm interested in:

1. Are there out-of-the-box features in SharePoint Online that I might have overlooked, which could solve this problem?
2. If a custom SPFx web part is the best solution, how should I go about dynamically fetching and updating the image from the SharePoint library?
3. Any examples, templates, or resources that could guide me in implementing this solution would be immensely helpful.

Background:
I have some experience with SharePoint but am relatively new to custom development like SPFx. Any advice or pointers in the right direction, including tutorials or learning resources, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and help!